# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore: 'No operations defined in spec!' problem after update of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer' package to 2.2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

we have .net core 2.1 mvc webapi project which uses Swagger.
we use following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.1" />
```

swashbuckle is configured in following way:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer();
services.AddApiVersioning();
services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

everything woks in such setup (`/swagger/v1/swagger.json` has all operations and definitions and UI is rendered properly -> having all controllers and actions, etc)

we are trying to migrate our .net core project from 2.1 to 2.2 .net core.

In order to do that (without warnings) we need upgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer` nuget from 2.1.2 to 2.2.0.

After this nuget update swagger.json (`/swagger/v1/swagger.json`) doesn't contain any `"paths": {}` and `"definitions": {}` and this results in swagger UI showing no controllers/actions (it renders: `No operations defined in spec!`

after upgrade package these package versions is updated:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="2.2.0" /> //was 2.1.2
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" /> //was 2.1.1
```

I've tried to upgrade swashbuckle version to v4.0.0 but it did not resolved the issue.

what im missing which packages needs to be updated also so `swagger.json` would be generated properly when using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 2.2.0` package ?
or i'm missing something else ?

Comment: i created github issue in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore repository and i also created 100% repoducible problem demo repository. details in: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1166#issuecomment-497800414

Comment: actually issue is not realted with swashbuckle. It lies somewhere in our project setup.

Comments added to github issue that swashbuckle can be removed entirerly and still ApiExplorer update causes routing not working.

Answer (score 34):

Just had the same issue, thought I'd share my solution too. Version 6.0.4.

I had to add the [ApiController] attribute to my controllers. Swagger must be using that for discovery.

Answer (score 5):

- change public methods in controllers to [NoAction] Attribute.
- Also, Change all actions with explicit action Methods to [HttpGet("api/get-customer")], [HttpPost("api/save-customer")] instead of [Route("api/get-customer")].

Comment: You are lifesaving! The documentation at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) should change.

Comment: The type of namespace NoAction could not found?

Comment: i just get "failed to load api definition"

Answer (score 5):

If you are using minimal API, you shouldn't use **.WithGroupName(groupName)**

```
        app.MapGroup($"/api/{groupName}")
            //.WithGroupName(groupName)
            .WithTags(groupName)
            .WithOpenApi();
```

The method is not available for

> "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0"

**if you are using Swashbuckle, consider using other alternatives.** [Swashbuckle is being removed in .NET 9.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54599)

Comment: This was helpful advice; I was following a template that used NSwag and was calling `WithGroupName`, but I'm using Swashbuckle and removing the `WithGroupName` call made the Swagger page show my methods.

Answer (score 3):

in my case
builder.Services.AddControllers();
was missing

Comment: That was the problem for me, thanks. I don't get why it isn't called by default when you create an API project.

Answer (score 2):

I found how to fix this issue (also posted to: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1166#issuecomment-497800414)

In short: i needed to change my HOST project SDK: from 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' to 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web'.

i did not find explicitly is it should be like that for sure (but default Microsoft template uses this SDK in .net core 2.2)

so it would be great if someone could explain why .Web SDK needs to be used after migration from .net core 2.1 to 2.2

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked fine for me. My application startup project is other than the project that contains the api itself.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the decorator

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was this:

At the controllers i had this:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

...and also the http verbs for each endpoint:

> [HttpGet] | [HttpPost] | ...

Then, I missed this configuration:

> options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

...because I had this: (missed a few chars...)

> options.GroupNameFormat = "v'VV";

...and it did not match with this:

> options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI V1.0");

Answer (score 0):

Calling both `app.UseSwagger();` and `app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sonic App"); });` can cause this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [ApiController] attribute to controllers. It works for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.4.0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 3 years ago and it is for another version of .Net.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yeah, I know, but I also fased this problem in new version of .Net, so it can be helpful for smb, who also use it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the problem was that the access modifiers in the controller were internal instead of public. After replacing everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: having something like `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "...")]` as an attribute on your controllers can also cause this error if configured inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add public before my controller, making application not find my controller at all, thus i did not see my controller in swagger ui

Changed

```
class MyController: ControllerBase
```

to

```
public class MyController: ControllerBase
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
public class MyController : Controller
```

to

```
public class MyController : ContollerBase
```

and

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ContollerBase
```

You may need to close and reopen the app.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:

**Program.cs:**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
 {
    c.SwaggerDoc(VersionControl.APIVersion, new OpenApiInfo { Title = $"My API - v{VersionControl.APIVersion}", Version = VersionControl.APIVersion });
  });
```

.
.
.

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.SwaggerEndpoint($"swagger/{VersionControl.APIVersion}/swagger.json",$"My API - v{VersionControl.APIVersion}");
  options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
 });
```

**Specify the GroupName of the controller:**

```
[ApiVersion(VersionControl.APIVersion)]
[Route("api/v{version:ApiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = VersionControl.APIVersion)]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

**File with version definition:**

```
internal class VersionControl
{
   internal const string APIVersion = "1.4";
}
```